# NSWindow event when change size of window

Tags: objective-c

what is method call when change size in Window?
I find somesing aboud `windowDidResize:` so i try doing

```
- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

I found what need use `NSWindowDidResizeNotification`, but I work for the first time with NSNotification and bad understand about this.
Can somebody write a full example for my event, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-windowDidResize:` method is called on the window delegate. Is the object with the method you posted the delegate for the window?

For something other than the delegate, you can do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidResize:) name:NSWindowDidResizeNotification object:theWindow];
```

and, when the observer is no longer interested or being deallocated:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSWindowDidResizeNotification object:theWindow];
```

Another approach is to use the new block-based API to `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
id observation = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSWindowDidResizeNotification object:theWindow queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *){
    NSLog(@"test");
}];
// store/retain the observation for as long as you're interested in it. When it's deallocated, you stop observing.
```

Comment: thank, but I don't understand in which method i must write this

Answer (score 0):

You can Implement NSWindowDelegate:

```
class YourVC: NSWindowDelegate {

    // This method trigger when you press the resize button in the window toolbar
    func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {
   
          // Write your code here   

    }
}
```

And, In viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear() method

```
 self.view.window?.delegate = self
```

You can also use other delegate methods:

- windowDidEnterFullScreen
- windowDidExitFullScreen
  ...